# How to compare Macbook Pro with other gaming notebooks?

Tags: macbook-pro, performance, games

Is the graphics card model enough to compare a notebook's gaming performance? If a non-Apple gaming notebook that has better external graphics card than MacBook Pro; does it mean that the game performance would be better?

We all know the how useful Mac OS X is as an operating system. But does it have a real impact for gaming performance?

Let me demonstrate my question. Think there are 2 notebooks like the specs defined as:

- Notebook A: NVidia GeForce GTX 980M, non-Apple notebook
- Notebook B: NVidia GeForce GTX 880M, Apple notebook

And assume that **all the other hardware specs are same**. Which notebook provides better gaming performance in terms of Frames Per Second (FPS)?

Comment: Hypothetical questions don't work so well here. If you can rewrite the question to focus on a real-world problem (which shouldn't be a shopping recommendation though), please do so.

Comment: actually I am not looking for a shopping recommendation; instead of that just asking the performance effect of an operating system in terms of facts. If I target getting a shopping advice, I would mention specific notebook models. @patrix

Answer (score 2):

## It Depends

<sub>a huge ***Depends*** really</sub>

**TLTR**: You can't do it. You have to test both in an real world task, in this Case the Game. It will be always a unfair competition. Some points to think about:

### Mac OSX and Metal

Since Apple Introduced [Metal](https://developer.apple.com/metal/) it is even harder to compare. In this Case, the game has to use Metal by Apple. If it uses *legacy* OpenGL, it won't give you a speedup. But if Metal is available and used, the game will run faster than on the same Hardware without Metal.

### Macbook and Bootcamp

I hade on some Steam Apps with my Macbook with OS-X better FPS than my Colleague (if i remember correctly a Alienware M14x.R2) with the same Graphic-Card as my Macbook Pro Retina 2012. Then i tried it with Bootcamp and i got 5% less FPS in Average case. So Mac OS (and it's Graphics Driver) is more performant in most tasks (even Games) *in my case* But you can not say it is 5% better in each task/case.

### FPS Comparison

Is alway bad, every benchmark is a test scenario and not a Real-Event. So the best way to find out is to install the Game on each Notebook and run the same Level with same Settings. You may also look at [Notebookcecks Benchmarks](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Benchmarks-Tech.123.0.html) Sometimes there are even MacBooks tested.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience @bMalum. These comparisons are useful to compare hardware such as `GPU`, `CPU`, `HDD`, etc. But the one I am looking for is the direct impact of `operating system` itself.

Comment: @talha06 I assumed in this answer all Components are the same. In my experience OSX is a bit more performant, but if you want to compare 2 different Graphic-Cards with 2 different Operating Systems you have to do some tests to get a answer on your Question for the 'Operating System' impact.

Comment: similar to the one you mentioned, tests on `2 different operating systems` that use `same graphics` cards can be enough to identify the performance affect of operating system too.

Comment: @talha06 definitely, in your Question are 2 different Graphics Cards that confused me now :D - If Metal is enabled Mac OSX wins for sure. With OpenGL it will depend on the Driver and Implementation, but i guess Mac will be a bit faster, but i do not guarantee.

Comment: this was just to reveal if the Mac OS X provides a real advantage - even with less capable hardware. If not, I asked if Mac OS X can provide performance with the same hardware.